# Make fullcalendar only show events for logged in user not all users

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using fullcalendar on my web site and I would like to know if I can make it only show the events for the usere that is logged in and not to all the users on the website. I have looked at all 2000 + questions and answers stackoverflow and could not find a answer to this questions.

Comment: Pretty easy, just fetch the events for that user only from your db.

Answer (score 7):

pretty simple. In event source,

```
eventSources:[ <?php if(userloggedin) echo $eventArray1; ?>,
               <?php if(userloggedin) echo $eventArray2; ?>]
```

check the condition and insert the event source.